# JQgrid on sorting data changes for ID column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am using JQgrid to display data, data in grid is added row by row. also i am using "local" data type to enable sorting on client side.
i am having 'id'in colmodel which stores database Id. at first time data is loaded properly
but when i click on header for sorting data content of 'id' column changes to 1,2 ...

please help..

my code

```
var pageNumber=0,
    previouslySelectedId,
    numberOfRecords;


var numberOfPages,sortingFlag=false;

$(function() {
     $("#supplierCommodityList").jqGrid({               
            datatype: "local",                          
            colNames:['ID','Supplier','Commodity','Unit','Cost Per Unit','Start Date','End Date'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'id',index:'id',hidden:true}, 
                {name:'supplier.name',index:'supplier.name',sorttype:"string",formatter:wrapToLinkFormatter},
                {name:'coProductSpecification.name',index:'coProductSpecification.name',sorttype:"string",sortable:true}, 
                {name:'unit',index:'unit',sorttype:"string"},
                {name:'expense',index:'expense',sorttype:"int"}, 
                {name:'startDateStr',index:'startDate',formatter:dateFormatter}, 
                {name:'endDateStr',index:'endDate',formatter:dateFormatter}     
            ],

            pager: '#supplierCommodityPager',          //require id pagination, contains id for pagination div.
            viewrecords: true,
            multiselect: false,      // to enable multiselect (chack box)
            caption: "Supplier Commodity",  //to show title on top      
            width: 920,
            height:600,
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: true, // to enable sorting on client side 
            sortable: true, //to enable sorting 
            onPaging:paginationEvent,    //pagination
            onSortCol:sortingEvent,
            gridComplete:gridCompleteFunction,
            editurl: "clientArray"
        }).navGrid('#supplierCommodityList',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

    attach_events(pagiantion_control_classes,'supplierCommodityList','supplierCommodityPager',get_supplier_commodity_details);
    sortingEvent.gridId='supplierCommodityList'; //Id of grid 
    sortingEvent.pagerId='supplierCommodityPager';//Id of Pager
    get_supplier_commodity_details(0);      
});


/**
 * method to get data .
 */
var get_supplier_commodity_details=function(requestedPage){ 
    if(typeof requestedPage == 'undefined')
        requestedPage=0;
    var rurl='supplierCommodity/false';
    $.ajax({
        url: rurl+'/'+requestedPage,
        processData:false,
        type: 'GET',

        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){                     
            render_supplier_commodity_details(data,requestedPage);
        }                               
    }); 
};

/**
 * method used to render data in grid, row by row
 * 
 */
 var render_supplier_commodity_details=function(data,pageNo){
     numberOfRecords=data.numberOfRecords;
     var numberOfPages=data.totalPages;
     var noOfRecordPerPage=0;
     console.debug(data);
        $.each(data.supplierCommodityList,function(i,row){
            $("#supplierCommodityList").jqGrid('addRowData',row.id,row);             
            noOfRecordPerPage+=1;
        });

        //alert(noOfRecordPerPage);
        $("#supplierCommodityList").setGridParam({rowNum:numberOfRecords});
        //jQuery("#supplierCommodityList").trigger("reloadGrid"); // to avoid total no of pages to be shown as 0.
        $('span#sp_1_supplierCommodityPager').text(data.totalPages); //shows total pages
        $('input.ui-pg-input').val(pageNo+1);
        $("#supplierCommodityList").setGridParam({rowNum:numberOfRecords});
        if(numberOfPages==1){
            $('#supplierCommodityPager .ui-paging-info').text('View '+ 1 +' - '+ noOfRecordPerPage+ ' of '+noOfRecordPerPage);
        }else if(numberOfPages==(parseInt(pageNo)+1)){
            var minrecord=numberOfRecords-noOfRecordPerPage+1;
            var maxrecord=numberOfRecords;
            $('#supplierCommodityPager .ui-paging-info').text('View '+ minrecord +' - '+ maxrecord+ ' of '+numberOfRecords);
        }else if(numberOfPages!=1){
        var minrecord=(noOfRecordPerPage*pageNo)+1;
        var maxrecord=noOfRecordPerPage*(pageNo+1)>numberOfRecords?noOfRecordPerPage  :noOfRecordPerPage*(pageNo+1);
            $('#supplierCommodityPager .ui-paging-info').text('View '+minrecord +' - '+ maxrecord+ ' of '+data.numberOfRecords);
        } 
};

/**
 * method handling sorting of column 
 */
sortingEvent=function(index,iCol,sortorder){//index=col. name, icol=index of column,sortorder=asc or desc
    // console.debug(index+ iCol+sortorder+"   satrt");
     sortingFlag=true;                                  //flag required in gridCompleteFunction to change Text in Pager.
     numberOfPages=$('span#sp_1_'+sortingEvent.pagerId).text();
    var pageNumber=$('#'+sortingEvent.pagerId+' .ui-pg-input').val();

        if(iCol== 6 || iCol==7){
            var obj=$("#"+sortingEvent.gridId).jqGrid('getRowData');
            console.debug(obj); 

            compareDate.sortorder=sortorder=='asc'?1:-1;  //for acending order directly return 1 if 1st element<2nd element
            compareDate.sortingField=(iCol==6)?'startDateStr':'endDateStr'; 
            obj.sort(compareDate);
            console.debug(obj); 
            var gridObj = jQuery("#"+sortingEvent.gridId);  
            var textOnPager=$('#'+sortingEvent.pagerId+' .ui-paging-info').text();
            gridObj.clearGridData();
            $.each(obj,function(i,row){
                $("#"+sortingEvent.gridId).jqGrid('addRowData',row.id,row);          //appends data row by row to grid  
            });
            $('#'+sortingEvent.pagerId+' .ui-paging-info').text(textOnPager);
            $('span#sp_1_'+sortingEvent.pagerId).text(numberOfPages); //shows total pages
            $('#'+sortingEvent.pagerId+' .ui-pg-input').val(pageNumber);
            return 'stop';
        }
};

/**
 * method called when we click on link for updating Headline
 */
clickMethod=function(id){
     if(id!=null && typeof id != 'undefined')
        window.location = "/kiss/portal/yoadmintool/supplierCommodity/supplierCommodityDetail/"+id+"/";
    else
        window.location = "/kiss/portal/yoadmintool/supplierCommodityList"; 
 };



 /*
  * method which gets called on pagination.
  */
 var paginationEvent=function(pgButton){
    pageNumber=$('#supplierCommodityPager .ui-pg-input').val();
    var gridObj = jQuery("#supplierCommodityList");  
    gridObj.clearGridData();
    get_supplier_commodity_details(pageNumber-1);   
 };




gridCompleteFunction=function(){   
var noOfRecordPerPage=jQuery("#supplierCommodityList").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
    if(sortingFlag){
        if(numberOfPages==1){
        $('#supplierCommodityPager .ui-paging-info').text('View '+ 1 +' - '+ noOfRecordPerPage+ ' of '+noOfRecordPerPage);
        }else if(numberOfPages==(parseInt(pageNumber)+1)){
            var minrecord=numberOfRecords-noOfRecordPerPage+1;
            var maxrecord=numberOfRecords;
            $('#supplierCommodityPager .ui-paging-info').text('View '+ minrecord +' - '+ maxrecord+ ' of '+numberOfRecords);
        }else if(numberOfPages==0){

        }else if(numberOfPages!=1){
        var minrecord=(noOfRecordPerPage*pageNumber)+1;
        var maxrecord=noOfRecordPerPage*(parseInt(pageNumber))>numberOfRecords?noOfRecordPerPage  :noOfRecordPerPage*(parseInt(pageNumber));
            $('#supplierCommodityPager .ui-paging-info').text('View '+minrecord +' - '+ maxrecord+ ' of '+numberOfRecords);
        } 
    }
    sortingFlag=false;
    $('.ui-state-disabled.ui-pg-button').removeClass('ui-state-disabled').addClass('ui-state-enabled');//to enable pager button
 };


 /**
  * method to wrap discription to link for updation purpose
 */
 wrapToLinkFormatter=function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
     var link="<a href=\"javascript:clickMethod('"+rowObject.id+"');\">"+cellvalue+"</a>";
     return link;
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen [the jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amorris/yNw3C/) many times and I am wonder where is the origin of it. The problem is that the demo is **really bad template**. It contains many small errors and shows *the worst way* to fill jqGrid with local data. Please never use the template for your real code.

The error which is in your current code is the following: you choosed `id` as the name of the first column. The `id` property will be used to save the rowid (the `id` of `<tr>` elements of the grid). On the one side you use `id: 48803` and `id: 48769`. On the other side you use `$("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);`. So the `id` will be set to `i + 1` (1 and 2). So the values `48803` and `48769` will be placed in the grid, but the `id` properties of internal `data` parameter will be *overwritten* to 1 and 2 values. If you would change the code to `$("#grid").jqGrid('addRowData', data[i][0], mydata[i]);` the problem will be solved.

Nevertheless I strictly recommend you to rewrite the code. You should first fill the `mydata` and then create the grid with `data: mydata` abd `gridview: true` options. You should additionally fix the `sorttype` to corresponds the data which you use. I recommend you additionally to use `height: "auto"` instead of `height: 250` and include pager. The current code will just display first 20 rows of the data (`rowNum` has default value 20) and the user will be not able to see the next page.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but this is sample code i took from net. in my code i am using id as string it will contain ID stored in database. eg. "pqrs---1222"

Comment: @swap: Sorry, but if you need some help you should post the code which has problems. It's not important where you get the code example. You should use it correctly. So you have to rename `id` column to any other name or use the same `id` parameter of `addRowData` as the value in `id` column.

Comment: i have modified my question as you suggested. i am fetching data from ajax call and adding data row by row to grid, my data is having nested objects so i used '.' operator, i tried  the same id parameter of addRowData as the value in id column, but i am still getting undefined for column which i bounded to nested object.